# Dates about sql ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following Oracle sql script, I only need all the records from yesterday.

and fch_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
and fch_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)

This is another sql oracle statement
and fch_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
and trunc(sysdate) - internal '1' SECOND

Is there a better way to have only all the records from yesterday?
Thanks for your help

I want to have all the records from yesterday but all without missing any records

Comment: _"Is there a better way..."_ - define "better". What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Not sure "better", but simpler. How about: fch_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) ?

Comment: @OldDog In Oracle a `DATE` **ALWAYS** has a time component. Your solution would get values that are equal to exactly midnight yesterday (and not any other time of day yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

1. ```sql
       fch_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
   AND fch_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
   ```

   Will always get all the values from yesterday regardless of what data type `fch_date` has.
2. ```sql
   fch_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
                AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
   ```

   Will get all values from yesterday is `fch_date` has the `DATE` data type but if anyone decides to alter the table so that `fch_date` is a `TIMESTAMP` then you will not match values between `23:59:59.000000001` and `23:59:59.999999999`.
3. The third option is:

   ```sql
   TRUNC(fch_date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
   ```

   While this will work, Oracle will not be able to use an index on `fch_date` and would require a function-based index on `TRUNC(fch_date)`.

Therefore:

- For a `DATE`, the first 2 options are equivalent; but
- If someone takes the same logic and applies it to a `TIMESTAMP` column then the first option is superior as the second option will not match all 24 hours. You should probably avoid the second option so you can ensure that consistent logic can be used for all date and time data types.
- The third option could be used but it disallows the use of an index so the first option should probably be preferred.